# C++: Serialize byte array to hex string

Tags: c++

I (C++ newbie) am currently trying to implement the following function:

```
std::string bytes_to_hex(const std::string &bytes);
```

The function should basically return a base16 encoding of a given byte array:

```
std::string input{0xde, 0xad, 0xbe, 0xef} => "deadbeef"
```

My first version doesn't quite work how I imagined:

```
std::string bytes_to_hex(const std::string &bytes) {
    std::ostringstream ss;
    ss << std::hex;

    for (auto &c : bytes) {
        ss << std::setfill('0') << std::setw(2) << +c;
    }

    return ss.str();
}
```

With this function the output is:

```
ffffffdeffffffadffffffbeffffffef
```

After some experiments, I've found out that this version looks better:

```
std::string bytes_to_hex(const std::string &bytes) {
    std::ostringstream ss;
    ss << std::hex;

    for (const char &c : bytes) {
        ss << std::setfill('0') << std::setw(2) << +(static_cast<uint8_t>(c));
    }

    return ss.str();
}
```

The output is as expected:

```
deadbeef
```

My question is:

- Why does the second version work and the first doesn't? What is the main difference here?
- Is the second version correct implementation of my original intention or can there be other problems?

Comment: The `+` does nothing, casting however did what you wanted, ie made sure the bytes are interpreted as positive numbers

Comment: Remember that the `char` type can be either `signed` *or* `unsigned`, it's up tot he compiler. In your case they seem to be `signed`, which means when the characters are [promoted to `int`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/conversion#Integer_promotions) they are also *sign extended*.

Comment: @PasserBy The unary `+` forces [*integer promotion*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/conversion#Integer_promotions) of the character.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I meant as in not changing its value

Comment: @bmk While a `std::string` can be used for arbitrary data, it does have its drawbacks. One of them you just discovered. That's why I always recommend `std::vector<uint8_t>` for arbitrary byte data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in my comment, the unary `+` forces [*integer promotion*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/conversion#Integer_promotions). When that happens, signed types are *sign extened* which for [two's complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two's_complement) encoded integers means that negative numbers (where the left-most bit is `1`) are left-padded with binary ones (i.e. `0xde` becomes `0xffffffde`).

Also mentioned is that `char` can be either `signed` *or* `unsigned`, a decision that is up to the compiler. Because of the output you get we can say that in your case `char` is actually `signed char`.

The simple solution you found out is to first cast the character to an `unsigned char`, and then (with the unary `+`) promote it to `int`.

Comment: thank you for the answer! Do you have also comment for my second question?

Comment: @bmk Your second solution will work fine, and should be portable. The only "improvement" might be an explicit `static_cast<unsigned>` instead of the `+` promotion, which is more to read and write, but expresses intent better (and will be clearer for those that don't understand promotion yet).